# Updating an Access Query definition (SQL) and reflecting in dependent queries

Tags: vba, ms-access, dependencies

I am still relatively new to Access and the functionality, but bottom line is I have a query (called *ScenarioQuery*), which pulls data from a table *ScenarioDetails* and creates columns which are equivalent to fiscal periods, so each column will be a calculated column like

```
 IIf(MonthNumber = 1, [Value], 0) AS [S2020Jan]
```

What I am trying to do is use VBA to dynamically update the year as part of the column aliases as each "scenario" will contain a different year range.

I have successfully set up the macros to update the years dynamically through using arrays and recordsets, however, **I have linked (dependent) queries which reference the field names in their own result sets and these don't update automatically when a query def is updated (at least as far as I know)**

Is there a way to accomplish this dependency chain update? Or would I either have to write further macros to update these queries / alter the objects to pull from another source ?

Comment: `for each q in querydefs:q.sql=replace(q.sql,"2020","2021"):next q`  I've not properly tested that, but i'd be looking at the querydefs.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `QueryDefs` collection, like so

```
For Each q In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
    q.SQL = Replace(q.SQL, "2020", "2021")
Next q
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydefs-collection-dao

Comment: Thank you for responding. I guess you're saying I'll need to programatically update the query column aliases then ? There is no function or line of code that will do what I need in the DB library??